# IF statement how can i input a word from the keyboread not just a char in java

Tags: java

[image]

always getting an error how to fix this ((  if (Choice == 'Borrow' || Choice == 'borrow')  ))

Comment: Please post your code instead of an image.

Comment: `charAt` returns character. You are comparing to a string. Also, in Java, single quotes are used for chars, and double for string. Use `equals()` for comparing

Comment: sorry 
here is the code
     Choice = zam.next().charAt(0);
              
              if (Choice == 'Borrow' || Choice == 'borrow'){

Comment: You use apostrophes for characters, not strings. Plus youre trying to compare à character to a string and doing it in a wrong way

Comment: to fix the problem and make it recognized by java a word not just a character what should i use sorry a beginner programmer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

luiscubal is right and if you want to compare the string instead of the first carachter, you can use `Choice = zam.next();` wich returns a `String` and compare it using `Choice.equals("Borrow")`.

---

You get an error when you on `Choice = zam.next()` because `zam.next()` returns a `String` and you probably declared `Choice` as a `char`.

Comment: i get an error when i use only this  Choice = zam.next() ;

Answer (score 1):

In Java, Strings should be quoted like `"this"`, not like `'this'`. The second syntax is used for individual characters.

Since you're using `charAt(0)`, you are already getting the first character of the string, so you should be comparing to the individual characters `'b'` and `'B'`.

Comment: what can i use to make it the whole word not just the first character sorry a beginner at java

Comment: `zam.next()`. No need for anything after that. But note that your string comparisons won't work because you should use `.equals` instead of `==`.

Comment: am.next( ) ; i get an error and i used .equals also the same problem error

Answer (score -1):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Veuillez saisir un mot :");
String str = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("Vous avez saisi : " + str);
if (src == "Borrow"|| Choice == "borrow"){
    System.out.println("You are borrow ");
}
```

Le mieux est d'éviter de faire des tests inutiles:

```
// supprime les espaces avant et apres le mot entré sur l'ui
String sansEspace = src. trim();
// remplace les majuscule par des minuscule
String formated = sansEspace.toLowerCase();
// faire qu'un seul test
if (formated == "borrow"){
    System.out.println("You are borrow ");
}
```

Comment: Two things: please write your text in english; and `formated == "borrow"` is still wrong.

Comment: use  double quote " and not ' . 
If you declare the String in the same bloc, it works

Comment: i made choice string worked fine but i get error on 

 if (Choice == "Borrow" || Choice ==  "borrow" )

Comment: use  zam.nextLine() instead of next()

Comment: i tried this and worked fine if ("Borrow".equals(Choice))

Comment: @Zam You should only accept the answer which solved your problem. This doesn't match to this answer, because it is flawed. So eiher you write or own answer with the fixes you've made to solve the question or you wait with accepting this answer after Mada updated this answer. Please mind that this page is supposed to be a Q&A page where people find answers to there problems (in programming). So if someone has a similar question like you, then he would think that the code in this answer is correct, but instead the solution is "hidden" in your comment.